# Dates between EF and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am using angularUI datepicker to get a date from UI, the binded date is formatted like this "2016-06-02T16:35:46.000Z" for local time "2016-06-02 07:35 PM" local time

but when reading that value from database after storing it using EF and web api over MVC4 I get the value without the Z which represents the UTC time.

The pure value is "2016-06-02T16:35:46" return in JSON when read using EF and WebAPI.

Is there a way to force webapi to return the time zone with the serialized date.